# HTML form space after and before text type

Tags: css

This is the code I have:

```
You have
<form name="cd" style="display: inline;">
<input id="time" readonly="true" type="text" value='10:00' border="0" name="disp">
</form>
left...
```

This is what's happening:
[image]

What I want to do is remove those space with the "red cross".
I already tried to add this css code:

```
form{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

But with no success...

Comment: Please post all the CSS that applies to your form.

Comment: I haven't any CSS code associated to that form. Only the `display: inline;`

Comment: What is altering the default styles of the input then?

Comment: Is the only purpose of your form to hold the readonly text field?  If so, why?  Why not use a span element to hold your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick everything in the same line, start with the form, and PLEASE don't use styles on the form tag.

```
<form name="cd">    
    You have <input id="time" readonly="true" type="text" value='10:00' border="0" name="disp"> left...
</form>
```

Comment: That's it MelanciaUK! But this is a little bit stupid...    About styles in form tag, don't worry! Is just for testing. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the form element. Instead try styling the input directly.

For example:

```
form input {padding:0;margin:0}
```